# Flexbox hover to make submenu txt appear only in hovered column

Tags: html, css, flexbox, elementor

I have this problem. 5 column flexbox. Each box to contain a header txt and suplementary txt under, but *only* on hover on that specific column. When unhover goes back to normal. Sounds easy enough, and I did it in codepen (rough model [here](https://codepen.io/dentalrejse/pen/ZajJdX). I am building in elementor, maybe thats causing the problem.When I hover 1 colunm supp. txt appears in all columns. Ref to page [here](http://dental-rejse.dk/flex-menu/)
I once before got great help from you guys, even though it turned out to be claimed a copy question. I spent 8 hours straight researching that this isn't the case this time.. if it is I apologize. 
Thanks in advance. Coding comes here:

```
 /* reset browser defaults */
* {margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box}
html, body {width:100vw;height:100vh}

.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh; /* mandatory (100% of the viewport height) */
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.container div{
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  transition: .3s;
  max-width: 20%;
  padding: 8em 0;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0.99;
}

.container div:hover {
  transition: .5s;
  max-width: 40%;
  flex-grow: 2;
  height: 100vh;
  cursor: pointer;
  background:#000;
  opacity: 0.7;

}

div:hover  p >  span p {
    color: #bf9456;
}


div :hover  a >  span {
    color: #bf9456;
}
```

and the HTML:

```
    <div class="container">
<div>
<p style="color: white;">OM OS</p>
<p><br />
 <a style="color: black;"><br />
 <span class="colo">VORES IDE</span></a></p>
</div>
<div>
<p style="color: white;">2</p>
<br />
 <br />
 <a style="color: black;"><span class="mogens">mogens</span></a></div>
<div><span style="color: #ff9900;">3</span></div>
<div><span style="color: #ff9900;">4</span></div>
<div><span style="color: #ff9900;">5</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry.. problem is that supplementaty txt appear in all columns on hover any column..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First simplify your codes, there is so much of `nesting`, markups here are different then on provided links.

You can use `nth-child` selector to make supplementary `text` fade-in on `hover` selected parent div,

```
.container > div:nth-child(1):hover p > span {
  color: #bf9456;
}

.container > div:nth-child(2):hover p > span {
  color: #bf9456;
}

.container > div:nth-child(3):hover p > span {
  color: #bf9456;
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.container div {
  color: #fff;
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  transition: .3s;
  max-width: 20%;
  padding: 8em 0;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0.99;
}

.container div:hover {
  transition: .5s;
  max-width: 40%;
  flex-grow: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0.2;
  color: #fff;
}

.a {
  flex: 1;
  color: #000;
}

.container > div:nth-child(1):hover p > span {
  color: #bf9456;
}

.container > div:nth-child(2):hover p > span {
  color: #bf9456;
}

.container > div:nth-child(3):hover p > span {
  color: #bf9456;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div>
    Make me over!
    <p style="color:black">
      <span class="colo">View Portfolio</span>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div>
    View Portfolio
    <p style="color:black">
      <span class="colo">Why would you say that?</span>
    </p>
  </div>
 
  <div>
    Help me!
    <p style="color:black">
      <span class="colo">Again..? Why would you say that?</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just what I needed.. perfect [here](http://dental-rejse.dk/flex-menu/) is the result so far.. hover is working, unfortunately like double-masking the overlay, but working like it is supposed to.. Still learning.. thanks

Comment: Welcome :-), nice menu.